# Pygame exit game and take input

Tags: pygame

I'm having some issues with my game in Pygame. I wanted the cross on the top right of Windows to exit the game if clicked. But it does not seem to work. I also want it to take input from the space bar and roll the dice.

```
diceRoll = random.randint(1, 4)

while True:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                diceRoll
```

The rest of the code falls under this but the screen goes black when I do the loop with this.

Comment: Show us your main loop.

Comment: Try with a break rather than `sys.exit()`. You could also move down `pygame.quit()` after your loop, so that it will be executed when the loop is done.

Comment: @MarcusMøller A `break` would only exit the inner `for` loop, not the outer `while` loop.

Comment: That is correct. He should do the main loop with boolean (`program_running` as an example) and set that to false on quit.

Answer (score 1):

To tell PyGame to quit correctly, you must do

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    pygame.quit()
    # perhaps force a quit using sys.exit()
```

If you're in a loop, you should also break that loop, using `break`

For the space bar event, you're already half-way there.

```
if event.key =0 pygame.K_SPACE:
    roll_dice()
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i do this with a loop my whole program goes black, so i can't see nothing

Comment: Consider using `sys.exit()` after `pygame.quit()`, or atleast show us your loop.

Comment: @user3099728 All your code should fall under a `while True` block! I suspect that is the cause for the program hanging.

Comment: That is usually perfectly fine. `while 1` is the same thing and it doesn't cause any problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a very big mistake with your first `if` statement. You are supposed to have the `event.type` lines in line with each other. You are doing this:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
```

when you should be doing this:

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    pass #Put your other code here
```

The second error is that you ***NEVER*** put `pygame.quit` in the while loop. It will exit the game/make the screen have nothing on it and make your program go crazy. The only logical way to *safely* exit the program *inside* the loop is with `sys.exit()`.So your new while loop should be:

```
while True:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                print 'diceRoll' #Doing diceRoll alone won't do anything
pygame.quit() #This is the proper location of this function
```

I hope this helps you!